# Differences between Jenkins directory and Git clonned directory

Tags: git, jenkins, centos7, objectmapper

For CICD tool, I installed Jenkins on Centos7.
When I create a new project via Jenkins, build by script in Jenkins and distribute project, everything goes fine.

However, when I git clone the same project and build by same script and distribute the project, custom objectMapper is not applied. My custom `objectMapper.java` is not found when `@RequestBody` from request.

What is differences between `Jenkins project directory` and `git clonned directory`???